# cant able to send mail from mail() in php (wamp server) locally

Tags: php

even i changed the php.in as
    [mail function]
    ; For Win32 only.
    SMTP = smtp.planetghost.com
    smtp_port = 25
    ; For Win32 only.
    sendmail_from = info@planetghost.com

```
<?php
$to = 'xxx123@gmail.com';
$sub = "hai all";
$mess = "this is for check";
$frm  = "pacha60@gmail.com";
$head = "From:".$frm;
mail($to,$sub,$mess);
?>
```

kindly solve it

Comment: @peeHaa i know it was asked already , my question is its not working properly , can you give solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$to` isn't a string. Change to:

```
$to = 'xxx123@gmail.com';
```

Comment: i changed , but not working

Comment: Then your problem is not in the code. `mail('email@address.com', 'This is a subject', 'This is a message');` should 100% work.

Comment: :i added a code <?php

mail('vickysoft.1990@gmail.com', 'This is a subject', 'This is a message');

?> but no mail came to my email

Comment: i am using wamp server 2.4 version

Comment: Yeah that should be fine. Take a look at the link that was added to the top of your question. Can't do anything without an error message, because there's nothing wrong with the code. I tested it too, it's fine.

Comment: @ vanamerongen: sir can you plz , say what changes should i do in php.in

Comment: Look just paste this at the top of your PHP file (not the ini, but the same file as your mail function, before the mail function call): `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Make sure to remove it after you figure out the problem though

Comment: on running <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mail('vickysoft.1990@gmail.com', 'This is a subject', 'This is a message');?> it runs without error . but no mail i recieved

Comment: No idea in that case... Can't really do anything with this if it doesn't give an error. The code is alright. Check the email address, check the spam folder, etc.